# Query instances related to other instance with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have `User` and `Property` models for my application.  I was originally using the Peewee ORM, but am switching to SQLAlchemy.  I want to select all properties listed by the current user and display them in a template.  In Peewee, iterating over the following query worked, but I get a `ProgrammingError` in SQLAlchemy.  How do I get the instances related to another instance in SQLAlchemy?

```
my_properties = Property.query.filter_by(listed_by=current_user)
```

```
{% for property in my_properties %}
    {{ property.listing_no }}
```

```
class Property(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    listed_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Peewee, a foreign key field does not separate the actual key from the thing it represents.  In SQLAlchemy, a foreign key column is only the key, a relationship is used to represent the thing it points to.

`listed_by` is an integer.  `current_user` is a proxy to a `User` object.  SQLAlchemy doesn't know what `integer == User` means.

Create a relationship to the User object and filter on that.

```
class Property(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True
    listed_by_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    listed_by = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=[listed_by_id])
```

```
Property.query.filter_by(listed_by=current_user)
```

---

Technically, you can also filter on the id field by passing the user's id, although it's usually more useful to define the relationship.

```
Property.query.filter_by(listed_by_id=current_user.id)
```